# Add rectangle with content inside background image

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS, and I want to add a rectangle in the middle right of the image and add some content inside it

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z1rmp9o/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="MyClass__background"> </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.MyClass{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  &__background {
    background-image: url(https://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/1920x1080/getty_509107562_2000133320009280346_351827.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

So I want something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06oQ1.png)

How can I achieve this? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can find great docs here https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.MyClass{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* add position relative this will prevent the children from moving out of the parent container */
  position: relative;
}

.MyClass__background {
    background-image: url(https://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/1920x1080/getty_509107562_2000133320009280346_351827.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
  }

.rectangle {
  position: absolute; /* will move the rectangle to the top left corner */
  right: 5px; /* move to the right with 5px space on the right with 5px space on the right */
  bottom: 50%; /* this and translate center the image vertically */
  transform: translateY(50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

/* Center and display the image & text side by side */
.rectangle-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
}

.rectangle-content img {
   margin-right: 50px;
   max-width: 100% /*make the image fit in the container*/
}
```

```html
 <div class="MyClass__background"> 
   <div class="rectangle">
     <div class="rectangle-content">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/128/64" alt="">
       <div>
         <p>Some Text</p>
         <p>Some Other Text</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Excelent! it works, how about if I want to center the overlay? can I do with this code?

Comment: Yes, read the docs in the links for more info, replace the value with the ones below to center the rectangle, also check  @Quasipickle for a different approach,  `.rectangle {
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add `.MyClass` to the div.  Then change your modifier class to use `--` instead of `__`, as what you're doing is modifying the block, not creating a new element (assuming BEM)

Then, since you've already given it `display:flex`, all you need to do is add `align-items:flex-end` to move its contents to the right, and `justify-content:center` to vertically center its contents.

Then, add an overlay element inside the outer element.  That's where you put your content.

https://jsfiddle.net/fgz8oab1/1/